# Cannot snap install podman on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, snap, podman

The commands say it all:

```
~> sudo snap refresh
All snaps up to date.
~> sudo snap install podman
error: snap "podman" is not available on stable but is available to install on the following
       channels:

       edge       snap install --edge podman

       Please be mindful pre-release channels may include features not completely tested or
       implemented. Get more information with 'snap info podman'.
~> sudo snap install --edge podman
error: The publisher of snap "podman" has indicated that they do not consider this revision to be
       of production quality and that it is only meant for development or testing at this point. As
       a consequence this snap will not refresh automatically and may perform arbitrary system
       changes outside of the security sandbox snaps are generally confined to, which may put your
       system at risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --devmode; if instead you
       want to install the snap forcing it into strict confinement repeat the command including
       --jailmode.
~> sudo snap install --edge podman --devmode
podman (edge) 0.11.1.1 from Lokesh Mandvekar (lsm5) installed
~> podman

Command 'podman' not found, did you mean:

  command 'pod2man' from deb perl (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.3)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Any idea how to get `podman` using snap / why this does not work?

Comment: Note that ```/snap/bin> ls -lrth | grep podman``` returns nothing. I also tried to add a symlink ```/snap/bin> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/snap podman```, then I get ```~> podman
internal error, please report: running "podman" failed: cannot find app "podman" in "podman"```. I can see ```/var/lib/snapd> tree -f | grep podman
│   ├── ./inhibit/podman.lock
│   ├── ./sequence/podman.json
│   ├── ./snaps/podman_389.snap
```

Comment: Also note that I can see the podman snap here: ```snap> ls | grep podman
podman```

Comment: that symlink really makes no sense, you're just wildly guessing things.

Comment: I found some explanations on some webpage that the symlink there was used to start the snaps, and it seems to match with a ```which code``` for example (I have VSC installed as snap), which returns ```/snap/bin/code```, which is a similar symlink to the one I tried. So only half guessing. But in the end it did not work.

Comment: yeah, honestly, putting `podman` in a snap doesn't make any *sense*; what are you trying to *achieve* here?

Comment: I am trying to install podman on my Ubuntu version, for which I could not find an apt package on the default repos (Ub 20.04). Rather than add an externap PPA, I thought it may be good to do a snap install, as podman seems available as a snap. Ideally I wanted to install it in sandbox mode with --jailmode (tried it before devmode, though I show the result in --devmode here). The rationale is that this way I would not need any sudoing on some external PPA, and if installing in --jailmode, that should be safer for my system.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't make *sense* to install podman in a snap. I mean, you do understand what podman *does*, right? How will "mapping file system locations to containers", "opening ports", "creating resource limit groups", "creating systemd units" map into what snaps are for?

Comment: (in short: Podman is quite nice, you should probably just update to a less old version of Ubuntu and install it using `apt` from Ubuntu's official sources. Ubuntu 22.04 is a long-term support version, and does come with podman.)

Comment: Maybe it is wrong of me indeed to try to install podman through a snap, this is fine enough. But still, I wonder if this is a separate thing - for example, if I try to run a podman command that violates snap isolation / sandboxing, I understand if it crashes on me / complains / stops etc; but I do not really understand how running a find ```snap install PKG``` command results in a state where ```PKG``` is not known to my system.

Comment: (and it does seem like quite a few users have installed podman through the snap manager and were happy with it; the internet has quite a few "traces" of it scattered around)

Comment: the very thing that podman *is* doesn't fit to the mental model of applications of snap...